# Chromium Webdriver with "--no-sandbox" is opening a fully transparent/invisible Chrome window

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, chromium

The relevant code is as follows:

```
    # find the Chromium profile with website caches for the webdriver
    chrome_options = Options()
    profile_filepath = "user-data-dir=" + "/home/hephaestus/.config/chromium/Profile1"
    chrome_options.add_argument(str(profile_filepath))
    
    # put chromium into --no-sandbox mode as a workaround for "DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist"
    chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    
    # start an automatic Chrome tab and go to embervision.live; wait for page to load
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("./chromedriver", options=chrome_options)
```

When I run this Python code (and import the needed libraries), I get the screenshot below. Chromium that was opened with the above code is on the right, and is transparent and glitching out.

[Desktop view with Chromium webdriver tab glitching out on the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zi8w.jpg)

I am able to enter web addresses and interact with the page, but I just can't see any of it. I'm not sure why.

I deleted and re-downloaded Selenium and Chromium, to no avail. I had to add the "--no-sandbox" option because it was getting another error that said "DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist".

I'm not sure what else is causing this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution that works for me!

1. Uninstall and reinstall Chromium completely. When reinstalling, check that your Chromium version matches with Selenium (which I didn't even know was a thing).
2. DO NOT run your Python code as a sudo user. I did "sudo python3 upload_image.py" and got the "DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist" error. When I ran just "python3 upload_image.py", it did not raise the error.
3. Do not use the option "--no-sandbox" when running as a non-sudo user ("python 3 upload_image.py"). For some reason, the "--no-sandbox" option also broke my Chromium browser in the same transparent/infinite way as I posted above.

Hope this helps someone in the future!